# Azure app service continuous deployment failure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have an Azure App Service with two deployment slots, prod and dev. I have continuous deployment configured from VSTS set up to the dev slot and it's been working fine for months but all of a sudden it fails when running the deployment command step. This is the log for that step.

```
Installed:
    81 package(s) to packages.config projects
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset". [D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\VendorPortalSite.csproj]
Services\Data\UserRepository.cs(303,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used [D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\VendorPortalSite.csproj]
  VendorPortalSite -> D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\bin\VendorPortalSite.dll
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset". [D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\VendorPortalSite.csproj]
  VendorPortalSite -> D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\bin\VendorPortalSite.dll
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset". [D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortal\VendorPortal.csproj]
  VendorPortal -> D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortal\bin\Release\VendorPortal.exe
D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.wap.targets(151,5): warning : WebJob schedule for NotifyTeacher will not be created. WebJob schedules can only be created when the publish destination is an Azure Website [D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\VendorPortalSite.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. [D:\home\site\repository\UploadTempData\UploadTempData.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset". [D:\home\site\repository\UploadTempData\UploadTempData.csproj]
  UploadTempData -> D:\home\site\repository\UploadTempData\bin\Release\UploadTempData.exe
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2673,5): error MSB4062: The "GetProjectProperties" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\VendorPortalSite.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\VendorPortalSite\VendorPortalSite.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d4069364ae5648";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.51102.2512\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

The warnings has always been there and never caused and issue before. I tried to delete and re-create the slot but that didn't help.

Comment: did u check the portal. probably your webjob is published and the schedule is not configured.

Comment: The webjob has been there for months without a schedule, it's not currently being used, and never caused in issue before. I deleted and re-created the VSTS connection for the again and now it's magically working again. No changes to my project or code.

Comment: Guess it is one of those weird update issues.